# Linguistic categories of verbs

Tags: category

Under what linguistic categorisation do the words `Simple`, `Continuous`, `Perfect`, `Perfect Continuous` get described ? I understand their relationship to the temporal tense as they are used for past. present, and future.

Comment: Isn't this just the same as your other question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/613011/language-categorisations?